# How do I keep Material UI's bottom navigation at the very bottom of the screen?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to figure out how to keep [Material UI's bottom navigation](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-bottom-navigation/#main-content) at the very bottom of the page so that, rather than always being visible, it only appears below the body's main content.

Here's how my content is rendering in my app:

```
return (
        <div id='appContainer'>
            <Header />
            <Nav currentPage={currentPage} handlePageChange={handlePageChange} />
            {renderPage()}
            <Footer />
        </div>
    )
```

This is the code I've got for my footer itself:

```
return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <CssBaseline />
            <AppBar position="fixed" id="footer" sx={{ top: 'auto', bottom: 0,  }}>
                <Toolbar disableGutters>
                    <Box sx={{ flexGrow: 1 }} style={{ display: "flex", justifyContent: "center", textAlign: "center", width: "100%" }} flexDirection="column">
                        <div id="upper-footer">
                            <img
                                src={Logo}
                                id="footer-logo"
                                style={{ width: "10%", marginTop: "10px", marginBottom: "10px" }}
                                alt="logo"
                                href="/"
                            />
                            <div id="social-icons">
                                <FacebookIcon sx={{ m:0.5 }}/>
                                <InstagramIcon sx={{ m:0.5 }}/>
                                <GoogleIcon sx={{ m:0.5 }}/>
                            </div>
                            <div id="footer-contact">
                                <Typography
                                    variant="h6"
                                    noWrap
                                    component="a"
                                    href="/"
                                    sx={{
                                        mr: 2,
                                        display: { xs: "none", md: "flex" },
                                        fontFamily: "montserrat, sans-serif",
                                        fontWeight: 700,
                                        color: "inherit",
                                        textDecoration: "none",
                                        // backgroundImage: "/assets/images/distressed-btn.svg",
                                    }}
                                >
                                    <a href='tel:0000000000' style={{ display: "flex", alignItems: "center", textDecoration: "none", color: "inherit" }}>
                                        <PhonelinkRingIcon sx={{ m:0.5 }}/> (000) 000-0000
                                    </a>
                                </Typography>
                                <Typography
                                    variant="h6"
                                    noWrap
                                    component="a"
                                    href="/"
                                    sx={{
                                        mr: 2,
                                        display: { xs: "none", md: "flex" },
                                        fontFamily: "montserrat, sans-serif",
                                        fontWeight: 700,
                                        color: "inherit",
                                        textDecoration: "none",
                                        // backgroundImage: "/assets/images/distressed-btn.svg",
                                        href: "#",
                                        alignItems: "center"
                                    }}
                                >
                                    <LocalActivityIcon sx={{ m:0.5 }}/> Tickets Available Soon
                                </Typography>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div id="lower-footer">
                            <p>More Content Here</p>
                        </div>
                    </Box>
                </Toolbar>
            </AppBar>
        </React.Fragment>
    )
```

Any help is greatly appreciated! :)